# Password Blacklists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, blacklist

I've got a blacklist of passwords that I don't want Users to be able to select when they're creating their account or changing there password in my Rails app.

I want this to be in a database table rather than a YAML file.

How can I refer/check if the user's submitted password exists in this list? What's a way to do it?

It doesn't feel right that I'd need o create an ActiveRecord Model for it etc.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I refer/check if the user's submitted password exists in this list? What's a way to do it?

If you encrypt your user passwords (like I hope you do), it's a little bit challenging to perform this check (in fact, that's exactly one of the purposes of salt encryption passwords).

You will need, for each user in your database, loop each password, encrypt it using your current encryption strategy and match the result with the encrypted string stored in the database for the user. If they do match, it means the user is using one of those passwords.

And that's for already stored passwords.

> I don't want Users to be able to select when they're creating their account or changing there password in my Rails app.

This is easier than previous step. When the user is signin up or updating the password, just compare the user-entered unencrypted password with the list you have. If there is a match, return a validation error.